# cordova error unable to open URL: file:///android_assets/www/cordova_plugin.js

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap first time and not succeeded in running it properly.

I downloaded a project from a link given [here](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/phonegap/myfirstphonegapplugin_a.zip). It's working properly but when i tried to use cordova-2.9.1 then nothing is working properly.

What i tried, replaced the `assets/www/cordova-1.6.1.js` file with the new `phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\cordova.js` of PhoneGap-2.9.1, which i downloaded from [here](http://phonegap.com/install/). And changed the JAR file too. The JAR is not in the downloaded cordova-2.9.1, i have created the JAR file from the given .java file inside `phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\src`

Here the code i added in `config.xml`

```
 <feature name="HelloPlugin">
  <param name="android-package" value="com.tricedesign.HelloPlugin"/>
</feature>
```

plz help me find out the solution to my problem.